# Can I add the same eventListner to an element twice but calling different functions?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Is it possible to give an element the same Event listener but with 2 different functions calls?

Something like this

`document.getElementById("searchBar").addEventListener("keyup", populateTable);`

`document.getElementById("searchBar").addEventListener("keyup", createButtons);`

I have tried doing this but from my experience I only ever get 1 of the event listener to fire off at all.

So I have a search bar in my program that when the user types into it, the table below sorts according to what the user has typed. This search bar and the table belongs to a module that someone else built but I am using for my project. In this module, the program adds an event listener "change" to the search bar to allow it to search the table every time the user types. For my program, I also want to add the same "change" Event listener to the search bar but I want to connect it to a function I created that will do something different. I still want the search bar to change the table when the user types into it, but I also want it to call the function I created.

I know I could just go into the module code and call my function from the event listener that the other person created but I want to see if there is a way for me to solve this without editing the module code.

Thanks!

Comment: They're not the same event listener, they're different events.

Comment: One is `change`, the other is `click`. The `change` event only fires on input elements, but `searchBar` is probably a DIV.

Comment: You certainly can add multiple listeners, that's why the function begins with `add` rather than `set`.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `keyup` event when someone is typing in the search bar. And probably your search bar is an `input` field.

Comment: my apologies for the confusion, I have edited the question, both event listeners are the same, they are both "keyup" but they call different functions. They are also in different files. The first EventListener(the one I did not create)  works and sorts the table, but the listener I created does not work, I can tell because if it did work there would be text in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a `main` function that calls both functions, and hook that up to the event listener. Let me explain what I mean:

```
var call_both = function() {
    populateTable();
    createButtons();
}
```

Then, just hook this to the event listener.

```
document.getElementById("searchBar").addEventListener("keyup", call_both);
```

Comment: I do like this idea and I might end up using it in my program, however, I was hoping to avoid touching the code that I did not create which is where one of the event Listeners is.

Comment: You should not have to touch any of it. Just make sure your script tags come in this order: 1: script tag with populateTable() and createButtons(), 2: script tag with my code above. You do not need to edit your previous code. If this answer solved your issue please mark it as correct by clicking the grey checkmark next to the question.